# listFiles(FileFilter) instead of listFiles(FileNameFilter)

Tags: java, io, filefilter

When I try to use the method `someFile.listFiles(FileFilter foobar)` I get the error

> The method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in the type File is not applicable for the arguments (FileFilter)

While the javadoc of File clearly contains: `public File[]  listFiles(FileFilter filter)`
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

How do I solve this?

PS: My code is:

```
    FileFilter folderFilter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "some filter";
        }
    };
    File[] foobars = someFile.listFiles(folderFilter);
```

Comment: Where's your import directive.  Did you accidently import the wrong FilteFilter instead of `import java.io.FileFilter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've imported

```
javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
```

instead of

```
java.io.FileFilter
```

Probably occurred when selecting the import from the IDE

If the correct import is used, the code should not compile due to the existence of the `getDescription` method which is [only found in the former](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html#getDescription%28%29). The description is used for display purposes on `JFileChooser` dialogs and doesnt apply here.